# Access Objective-C Category's Property (Associated Reference) in Swift 3's Value Type

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, associated-object, objc-bridging-header

In my Objective-C class's .h file, I have created a Category for NSIndexPath like this:

```
@interface NSIndexPath (YVTableView)

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger subRow;

@end
```

and in that class's .m file, I have implemented that like:

```
static void *SubRowObjectKey;

@implementation NSIndexPath (YVTableView)

@dynamic subRow;

- (NSInteger)subRow
{
    id subRowObj = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, SubRowObjectKey);
    return [subRowObj integerValue];
}

- (void)setSubRow:(NSInteger)subRow
{
    id subRowObj = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:subRow];
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, SubRowObjectKey, subRowObj, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

Now, when I am accessing the subRow property of NSIndexPath in Swift 3 using IndexPath then its giving me error:

> Value of type 'IndexPath' has no member 'subRow'

If I am trying to access it using type casting

```
let subIndexPath = indexPath as NSIndexPath
let subRowIndex = subIndexPath.subRow
```

its always returning me '0' as 'subRow' value. May be its because IndexPath is value type and NSIndexPath is reference type.

I have implemented UITableViewDelegate to my Custom Delegate using Objective-C and implemented it to Swift class but in Swift where I am implementing the Custom Delegate methods, I am facing this issue.

I also tried to use NSIndexPath instead of IndexPath in my Custom Delegate implementation (Swift code) but it was giving me the error "Type YVViewController does not conform to protocol, Candidate has non matching-type".

Here is my Custom Delegate declaration :

```
@protocol YVTableViewDelegate <UITableViewDelegate>

@required

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(SKSTableView *)tableView cellForSubRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end
```

Its working perfectly fine with Swift 2.x but after migrating to Swift 3, I am facing this issue.

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to set a value other than 0 to `subRow`? I just tried your code and it worked ok for me.

Comment: No it have value in Objective-C -> UITableViewDelegate's subclass then using custom delegate I am passing it to Swift class but in Swift -> Custom Delegate implementation. I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `subRow` associated with an `NSIndexPath` will not be associated with an `IndexPath` casted from that `NSIndexPath` because they are not the same "object". `IndexPath` is a value type in Swift, defined with the `struct` keyword, so it cannot have an Objective-C associated object.

So even if you have set a value to `subRow` of an `NSIndexPath` in Objective-C code, the value is lost when that `NSIndexPath` is casted to Swift's `IndexPath`. That's why when you again cast the `IndexPath` back to `NSIndexPath`, the `subRow` value is always 0, which is the default value.

In your case, you need to declare the protocol in Swift and specify the index path parameter type as `NSIndexPath`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: SKSTableView, cellForSubRowAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Comment: What's the solution for my problem ? How can I use that Objective-C code in Swift 3 ?

Comment: I just updated the answer @Yash. In your Swift custom delegate implementation, declare the parameter type as `NSIndexPath` instead of `IndexPath`.

Comment: I already tried to use NSIndexPath instead of IndexPath in my Custom Delegate implementation (Swift code) but it was giving me error "Type YVViewController does not conform to protocol, Candidate has non matching-type".

Comment: You have to change the type in your protocol declaration as well.

Comment: Added my Custom Delegate declaration also in question.

Comment: How about declaring your protocol in Swift instead?

Comment: Ofcourse I can do that but thats not a solution of my question, thats a different way to do the things.

Comment: The question has essentially become how to use Objective-C associated object for Swift value types.

Answer (score 1):

You can however update your category as follows:-

```
- (NSInteger)subRow
{

    id myclass = [SKSTableView class];
  //  id subRowObj = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, SubRowObjectKey);
    id subRowObj = objc_getAssociatedObject(myclass, SubRowObjectKey);
    return [subRowObj integerValue];
}

- (void)setSubRow:(NSInteger)subRow
{
    id subRowObj = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:subRow];

    id myclass = [SKSTableView class];
   // objc_setAssociatedObject(self, SubRowObjectKey, subRowObj, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    objc_setAssociatedObject(myclass, SubRowObjectKey, subRowObj, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```